# Alternative to New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy on Hyperscale Database

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I am working on Microsoft Azure, in which I have a group of resources for a test environment and a production environment, in both I have an Azure SQL Databases database server with its respective database.
I am creating a Runbook of Automation Accounts in Powershell in another Microsoft Azure account (Important Note) that is responsible for "Copying" the production database to tests. I know that there is the `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy` command, however, this command does not It works with Hyperscale databases.
Is there an alternative to this command in Hyperscale? or in this second account it is possible to create a. Bacpac remotely with Azure commands for Powershell, all I have seen are for working on the same account, but the database account is different from the automation account due to work rates.
Thank you in advance for your help and comments.

I already tried to use the `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` command, but it seems to work only in the same Azure Account, and I can't specify "Azure Account for backup" and "Azure account for storage". Am I right?

Comment: Is that your sql server and storage account in the different Azure tenant and Azure subscription? Besides, could you tell me what is "Azure Account for backup" and "Azure account for storage"?

Comment: To your first question, yes, there are two differents Azure Tentant and Azure subscriptions.
With "Azure account for backup", i'm asking if in this comand `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport`
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabaseexport?view=azurermps-6.13.0) can i specify one Azure account for the database and another for the storage?.

Comment: According to my research, his command ```New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport``` can't do that. According to your need, I suggest you join one Azure AD account in the two Azure AD tenants and make the account become the two subscriptions' owner. Then you can use the command ```Select-AzureRmSubscription``` to choose which subscription you use.

Answer (score 0):

[Database copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale) is currently not available for Azure SQL Hyperscale but you may see it in public preview in a few months.

Comment: Can you give me the source of that information please, because i can do the job "Manually" meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alberto Morillo says in his comment `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy` it's currently not available for Azure SQL HyperScale. at least at the moment of this answer.

So i try to use `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` with 2 Azure Accounts and it's tottally possible, you need to login with the Azure Account of the origin database `Connect-AzureRmAccount` then you need to call the `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` command with the following parameters.

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport 
    -ResourceGroupName          $RGName # Resource group of the source database
    -ServerName                 $Server # Server name of the source database
    -DatabaseName               $Database # Name of the source database 
    -AdministratorLogin         $User # Administrator user of the source database
    -AdministratorLoginPassword $Pwd # Password of the source database
    -StorageKeytype             "StorageAccessKey" # Key type of the destination storage account (The one of the another azure account)
    -StorageKey                 $StorageKey # Key of the destination storage account(The one of the another azure account)
    -StorageUri                 $StorageFileFullURI # The full file uri of the destination storage (The one of the another azure account)
# The format of the URI file is the following:
# https://contosostorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/backupscontainer/backupdatabasefile.bacpac
```

unfortunately, this command is not enabled for hyperscale, so I get the following error message:

> New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport : 40822: This feature is not available for the selected database's edition (Hyperscale).

I used the same command with a database that was not Hyperscale and it worked perfectly.

Finally, I think I will have to perform the manual process for at least a few months, have Microsoft launch the update for HyperScale